# Jetpeck Compose hide cursor in OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, kotlin, cursor, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

How can the cursor in an `OutlinedTextField` be hidden? I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. My input needs a border, so I don't think I can use another component than `OutlinedTextField`.

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {},
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    singleLine = true,
    maxLines = 1,
    shape = inputCornerShape,
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        focusedBorderColor = Color(0xFF6650a4),
        unfocusedBorderColor = Color(0xFF625b71),
        cursorColor = Color.Transparent,
        errorCursorColor = Color.Transparent
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .weight(1f)
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .indicatorLine(
        enabled = false,
        isError = false,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            errorIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            cursorColor = Color.Transparent,
            errorCursorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        focusedIndicatorLineThickness = 0.dp,
        unfocusedIndicatorLineThickness = 0.dp
    )
)
```

Comment: When i'm trying your code, cursor not showing. What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the cursor using **`cursorColor = Color.Transparent`** in the `colors` attribute. You should also apply the same color to the text selection applying a custom **`TextSelectionColors`**:

```
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        singleLine = true,
        maxLines = 1,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Color(0xFF6650a4),
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color(0xFF625b71),
            cursorColor = Color.Transparent,
            errorCursorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found out that apparently settings the cursor color only didn't work when I set it from a parameter (like in my question). As soon as I copied the default value of the parameter and pasted it as the value of `color` it started working. That's when I realised I didn't include `cursorColor` and `errorCursorColor` when instantiating my Composable. I added other colors there, but not these ones. I thought they would be added, but instead, the entire `TextFieldColors` object is overwritten (obviously). When I added `cursorColor` and `errorCursorColor` here too, it started working. Derp.